# Python normal distribution plot with fixed xlabels

Tags: python

I am new to python and spent last two days to have normal distribution plot.
i have a list h = [33,186,67,180,90,78] but i want the x-axis to have a fixed string values
for each index for instance `xlabels = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']`
i tried

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import pylab as plt

h = sorted([33,186,67,180,90,78])  #sorted

fit = stats.norm.pdf(h, np.mean(h), np.std(h))  #this is a fitting indeed


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(h,fit,'-o')

ax.hist(h,normed=True)      #use this to draw histogram of your data
labels = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
ax.set_xtick = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.plot()
```

I  do not get it correct for some reason, any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this give a desired output?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import pylab as plt

h = sorted([33,186,67,180,90,78])  #sorted

fit = stats.norm.pdf(h, np.mean(h), np.std(h))  #this is a fitting indeed


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(h,fit,'-o')

ax.hist(h,density=True)      #use this to draw histogram of your data
labels = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']

plt.xticks(ticks=h, labels=labels)
plt.show()
```